# Angular: Cannot display the content from HTTP Response using *ngFor

Tags: html, angular, httpresponse

I tried to load the content from HTTP response to html view in the angular. I have initialized a array call 'list' to get the data. But its not visible while debugging. I don't know the issue. I'm just a beginner in angular.

```html
<table class="table table-hover">
  <th>
  </th>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of api.list">
    <td (click)="populateForm(item)">{{ item.FirstName }}</td>
    <td (click)="populateForm(item)">{{ item.LastName }}</td>
    <td (click)="populateForm(item)">{{ item.Country }}</td>
    <td (click)="populateForm(item)">{{ item.Phone }}</td>
    <td (click)="populateForm(item)">{{ item.FavoriteFood }}</td>
    <td (click)="populateForm(item)">{{ item.Comment }}</td>            
    <td>
      <i class="far fa-trash-alt fa-lg text-danger" (click)="onDelete(item.TestRegisterId)"></i>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

i'm also attaching the behind code also. I have included the service in ngOninit().

```html
  ngOnInit() {
    this.api.refreshList();
  }
```

The refreshList function is here.

```html
  refreshList(){
    this.http.get(this.rootURL)
      .toPromise()
      .then(res => this.list = res as RegisterModel[]);
  }
```

my html page looks like this,[image]

My database has 4 records, so i can see the 4 delete button. But data is not showing, i don't know why. Anyone please help me ?

Comment: did you import httpClient module?

Comment: Read this... https://dev.to/jwp/angular-why-doesn-t-my-data-show-up-4efm

Answer (score 1):

Just change "this.list" to "this.api.list" (make sure you already defined "list" array in your "api"):

```
    refreshList(){
        this.http.get(this.rootURL)
          .toPromise()
          .then(res => this.api.list = res as RegisterModel[]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that due to asynchrony you are trying to render the list when it has not yet come from the server.
you can try not rendering the list while the variable is undefined with `*ngIf = this.list`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping on `api.list`, you need to loop our `list`, the one you have initialised.

```
  <table class="table table-hover">
  <th>
  </th>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of list">
    <td (click)="populateForm(item)">{{ item.FirstName }}</td>
    <td (click)="populateForm(item)">{{ item.LastName }}</td>
    <td (click)="populateForm(item)">{{ item.Country }}</td>
    <td (click)="populateForm(item)">{{ item.Phone }}</td>
    <td (click)="populateForm(item)">{{ item.FavoriteFood }}</td>
    <td (click)="populateForm(item)">{{ item.Comment }}</td>            
    <td>
      <i class="far fa-trash-alt fa-lg text-danger" (click)="onDelete(item.TestRegisterId)"></i>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or if you want to loop over `api.list`, you need to set data to `this.api.list` not to `this.list` as below

```
 refreshList(){
    this.http.get(this.rootURL)
      .toPromise()
      .then(res => this.api.list = res as RegisterModel[]);
  }
```